# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when uploading to vimeo

Tags: api, laravel, vimeo

Hey when i use the api to upload a video like 334m from my site to vimeo it returned to me this error with no details any suggestion please and is it different from pro to regular user in upload size below 500m (failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET by the way it works with small videos i uploaded 127m video and it uploaded well so the problem i think with huge videos ?

Comment: Please use punctuation marks when writing questions. Sentences usually end with a period ".".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection reset errors are to be expected. Any time you encounter any error while transferring files to the Vimeo upload servers you should verify the progress of your upload: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#verify-the-upload and then resume uploading from where you left off.

Comment: no no it happened a lot with me every time i upload large video to vimeo when i upload small videos it work's great

Comment: Yes, that's to be expected. The longer it takes you to upload a video, the higher chance of an accidental, or intentional connection reset. No matter what happens, when making the PUT request sending the bytes to vimeo, if your connection ends, fails, times out, etc, you should verify the progress of the upload. The only time you can be confident the upload fails is if the verify check fails.

Comment: so what i have to do know ?